# How to mock Mage_Admin_Model_Session to use getUser method?

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit

I'd like to test a method with different admin-user, I mocked the admin session with this code:

```
$stubAdminSession = $this->getModelMockBuilder('admin/session')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(null)
        ->getMock();
$stubAdminSession->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getUser')
        ->will($this->returnValue(Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($data['user_id'])));

$this->replaceByMock('singleton','admin/session', $stubAdminSession);
```

but when I call the follow instruction

```
$admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
```

the admin variable is null.
In debug mode I can see the matchers array inside the

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')
```

with correct stub and the correct methodNameMatcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling

```
setMethods(null)
```

you explicitly state that no methods should get replaced. Therefore, the subsequent instruction has no effect.

Try this instead:

```
$stubAdminSession = $this->getModelMockBuilder('admin/session')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array('getUser'))
        ->getMock();
```